# Middleware OR other middleware validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, middleware

I need to check if a user is an administrator OR if the user is the same as the one requested. I tried but in one case it doesn't work.

```js
router.get('/:id', isSigned, isSameUser || isAdmin, getUser)
```

Is there a way to do what I want without creating a dedicated function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a different middleware to avoid unnecessary middleware chaining, which you can call `Auth` or `AuthMiddleware`, the name you want is up to you. In this middleware you could do the logic for checking the user's authentication status, something similar to this:

```js
function AuthMiddleware(request, response, next) {
  if(isSigned) {
    // User is signed in, so we can proceed doing the next check

    if(isSameUser || isAdmin || getUser) {
      // Validation checks out, go to next middleware without warnings.
      return next();
    } else {
      // User failed to show some ID and cannot access the page.
      return next(new Error("Unauthorized."));
    }

  } else {
    // The user has not signed in to your application
    return next(new Error("Unauthenticated"));
  }
}

router.get('/:id', AuthMiddleWare, (request, response) => {
  // DO LOGIC
});
```

Place this middleware inside a new file, and every time you need it, you can just import it rather than copy and paste the same code over and over.

`!` Note that this is a rough sketch code just to put you on the right track, so you most likely have to adjust this snippet to your own needs and logic.

The benefits of having a single authentication middleware, is so you can use it on every route, so you don't have to use so many chaining in your requests.

Comment: Okay, I see how I can do that. It's sad that we can do this more easily.... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Clément-Sn0w It's okay though, we're all learning to improves ourselves in programming, right?

Comment: Of course we do!